# How to read from a local file and run a script on the current open page and display file content on the text field using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Problem statement:
1. I want to read a local file based on user selection 
2. Display the file content on the Text field of the current active page

Manifest

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Click to execute",
  "description": "Testing read file",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs","all_urls","activeTab"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  
  "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
        ],
    "js": ["content.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
  
}
```

popup.js

```js
 
  function openfile1(event) {
    var input = event.target;
     var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      var text = reader.result;
      console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
   displayintext(text);
  // alert("File Content----"+reader.result.substring(0, 500));
    };
     reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
 
function displayintext(finalvalue)
{
 var f1 = finalvalue;
 alert("finalvalue   "+ f1);
 //chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "var Sbonus= getTextInControl("AH_5fOTHER_5fBONUS_5fGRAND_5fTOTAL"); alert(Sbonus);"});   
}
  document.getElementById('opentest').addEventListener('change', openfile1, false);
```

Content.js

```js
/*
var Sbonus= getTextInControl("AH_5fOTHER_5fBONUS_5fGRAND_5fTOTAL");  
var SpliAmt = Sbonus /4;  
console.log(Sbonus);
setTextInControl("AH_5fOFFER_5fOTHER_5fBONUS_5fAMT_5f1",SpliAmt); 
setTextInControl("AH_5fOFFER_5fOTHER_5fBONUS_5fAMT_5f2",SpliAmt); 
setTextInControl("AH_5fOFFER_5fOTHER_5fBONUS_5fAMT_5f3",SpliAmt); 
setTextInControl("AH_5fOFFER_5fOTHER_5fBONUS_5fAMT_5f4",SpliAmt); 
console.log(SpliAmt);
```

i am completely new to chrome extension development. i am unable to get the code to working. the extension is able to read the file and display the content on the alert.

Now, i want to execute the content script to read the value of a text field from the current active page which is in `content.js` and paste the value from the previous file content on one of the text field.

Any help is greatly appreciated.